Flutter app restarts after it is minimised [Only for iPad, Working for other Devices]
Facing strange issues only on iPad for app build with Flutter. Once we put the app in a minimized state and come back from the recent screen or on click of app icon, app is restarted again.
Here are the sample videos for both iPhone and iPad.
iPhone [Working]: Video link
iPad [Not Working]: Video link
Need a solution or workaround to maintain the same state while the app is minimized so that the user can resume from the same state. [Without restarting the app]

Need to turn off Fast App Termination if that is turned on in the Developer Setting of iPad or iPhone. Which will store the app state and resume when it is open from the background.
Flutter issue reference link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/149804
